# Ruby, including module in current directory

Tags: ruby

I am currently working through the Well Grounded Rubyist.  Great book so far.  I am stuck on something I don't quite get with ruby.  I have two files

In ModuleTester.rb

```
class ModuleTester
  include MyFirstModule
end

mt = ModuleTester.new
mt.say_hello
```

In MyFirstModule.rb

```
module MyFirstModule
  def say_hello
    puts "hello"
  end
end
```

When I run 'ruby ModuleTester.rb', I get the following message:

ModuleTester.rb:2:in `<class:ModuleTester>': uninitialized constant ModuleTester::MyFirstModule (NameError)
    from ModuleTester.rb:1:in`'

From what I have found online, the current directory isn't in the the namespace, so it can't see the file.  But, the include statement doesn't take a string to let me give the path.  Since the include statement and require statements do different things, I am absolutely lost 
as to how to get the include statement to recognize the module.  I looked through other questions, but they all seem to be using the require statement. Any hints are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You use `require` to load a file, not `include`. :-)

First, you have to `require` the file containing the module you want to `include`. Then you can `include` the module.

If you're using Rails, it has some magic to automagically `require` the right file first. But otherwise, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: Under 1.9.2+ you will either need to put the current directory in the load path (e.g. `$: << '.'`) or just use `require_relative 'MyFirstModule'`. And then, if you like, `include` it.

Answer (score 4):

You need to `require` the file before you can use types defined in it. *

```
# my_first_module.rb
module MyFirstModule
  def say_hello
    puts 'hello'
  end
end
```

Note the `require` at the beginning of the following:

```
# module_tester.rb
require 'my_first_module'

class ModuleTester
  include MyFirstModule
end

mt = ModuleTester.new
mt.say_hello
```

The `require` method actually loads and executes the script specified, using the Ruby VM's load path (`$:` or `$LOAD_PATH`) to find it when the argument is not an absolute path.

The `include` method, on the other hand actually mixes in a `Module`'s methods into the current class. It's closely related to `extend`. The Well Grounded Rubyist does a great job of covering all this, though, so I encourage you to continue plugging through it.

See the [#require](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Kernel.html#M001418), [#include](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Module.html#M000440) and [#extend](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M001002) docs for more information.

---

* Things work a bit differently when using [Rubygems](http://docs.rubygems.org/) and/or [Bundler](http://gembundler.com/), but getting into those details is likely to confuse you more than it's worth at this point.